# Spring4Shell: Security Analysis of the latest Java RCE '0-day' vulnerabilities in Spring (CVE-2022-22965 and CVE-2022-22963)

Tags: artifactory

Regarding the "spring4shell" vulnerability in https://www.lunasec.io/docs/blog/spring-rce-vulnerabilities/ .
Does anyone know if this vulnerability affects JFrog Artifactory Cloud or On-Premise versions?

Have searched support but have not seen an official response as yet hence asking the question more publicly.

Answer (score 5):

I work for JFrog.

The JFrog Platform (including Artifactory) is not affected by the Spring4Shell vulnerability (CVE-2022-22965) and Spring Cloud Function vulnerability (CVE-2022-22963).

This covers both the cloud version and the on-prem one (which share the same code base).

Here is a link to a [detailed remediation cookbook](https://jfrog.com/blog/springshell-remediation-cookbook/).

Comment: As I see Eldad Assis works for JFrog (based on his StackOverflow profile), but if u need better source here it is:
https://jfrog.com/blog/springshell-remediation-cookbook/